# Efficient way of updating texture in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, jogl

I wanted to render multiple video streams using OpenGL. Currently I am performing using glTexImage2D provided by JOGL and rendering on Swing window. 
For updating texture content for each video frame I am calling glTexImage2D. I want to know is there any faster method to update texture without calling glTexImage2D for each frame.

Answer (score 8):

You will always be using `glTexImage2D`, but with the difference that data comes from a buffer object ([what is this?](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object)) rather than from a pointer.

What's slow in updating a texture is not updating the texture, but synchronizing (blocking) with the current draw operation, and the PCIe transfer. When you call `glTexImage`, OpenGL must wait until it is done drawing the last frame during which it is still reading from the texture. During that time, your application is blocked and does nothing (this is necessary because otherwise you could modify or free the memory pointed to before OpenGL can copy it!). Then it must copy the data and transfer it to the graphics card, and only then your application continues to run.
While one can't make that process much faster, one can make it run *asynchronously*, so this latency pretty much disappears.

The easiest way of doing this is to for video frames is to [create a buffer name](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glGenBuffers.xml), bind it, and [reserve-initialize](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBufferData.xml) it *once*.
Then, on each subsequent frame, discard-initialize it by calling `glBufferData` with a null data pointer, and fill it either with a [non-reserving](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBufferSubData.xml) call, or by [mapping the buffer's complete range](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glMapBufferRange.xml).

The reason why you want to do this strange dance instead of simply overwriting the buffer is that this will not block. OpenGL will synchronize access to buffer objects so you do not overwrite data while it is still reading from it. `glBufferData` with a null data pointer is a way of telling OpenGL that you don't really care about the buffer and that you don't necessary want the *same* buffer. So it will just allocate another one and give you that one, keep reading from the old one, and secretly swap them when it's done.

Since the word "synchronization" was used already, I shall explain my choice of `glMapBufferRange` in the link above, when in fact you want to map the whole buffer, not some range. Why would one want that?
Even if OpenGL can mostly avoid synchronizing when using the discard technique above, it may still have to, sometimes.
Also, it still has to run some kind of memory allocation algorithm to manage the buffers, which takes driver time.  `glMapBufferRange` lets you specify additional flags, in particular (in later OpenGL versions) a flag that says "don't synchronize". This allows for a more complicated but still faster approach in which you create a single buffer twice the size you need once, and then keep mapping/writing either the lower or upper half, telling OpenGL not to synchronize at all. It is then your responsibility to know when it's safe (presumably by using a fence object), but you avoid all overhead as much as possible.

Comment: all except the first link are dead.

Comment: How do you known `glTexImage2D` would block until the glDrawXX is finished?  I can not  find  this knowledge in the opengl document.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the texture without updating the texture.

---

Also I don't think that one call to `glTexImage` can be a real performance problem. If you are so oh concerned about it though, create two textures and map one of them for writing when using the other for drawing, then swap (just like double-buffering works).

If you could move processing to GPU you wouldn't have to call the function at all, which is about 100% speedup.